# Issue with posting variable created with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, ajax

This is a tough one.. I am attempting to use ajax for the first time. basically upon selecting an option from the first field, js and xml run a php script which creates the next dropdown based of of information it pulls from an SQL table. Surprisingly everything works pretty well, for my first attempt. the problem  comes when you run the final query the variable that should be posted over (`$_POST['ports'];`) evaluates to a single white space character, not the value selected in the  tag. time for the code:

html:

```
<h1>Enter port data to set how your table will look</h1>
<select style="width:150px;" onChange="showUser(this.value)">

<option value="">Select A Table Type</option>
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="247">Custom</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="select2">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function showUser(str){
document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('select2').innerHTML="";
if(str===""){
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('select2').innerHTML="";
    return;
}

if(str==="247"){
    document.getElementById('hide').style.display='block';
    return;
}

// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

// code for IE6, IE5
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

//set up return
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
document.getElementById("select2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethtml.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

gethtml.php

```
//include connection
include 'log.php';

//get vars
$q=$_GET['q'];

//make the query
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Model 
FROM tbl
WHERE Manufacturer = '".$q."'";

//make the new box
echo '<select name="ports" style="width:150px;">';
echo '<option>Select A Port Total</option>';
$i=1;
foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
echo $row['Model'];
echo '<option value="'.$row['Model'].'">'.$row['Model'].'</option>';
$i++;
}
echo "</select>";
```

so, everything is sent to gethtml.php. the query runs correctly, the `<select>` box is there, however there seems to be an error with the `<select>` part of it, and i just cant figure out what that is. Here is a snippet from the submission php the runs after you submit the form that the `<select>` is messing up on.

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
[ports] => 
)
```

I know you can't tell, but when i highlight that bit, there is a whitespace character there, i even ran it through an `isset()` to see it i was right and there is a character there.

here is an image of the xml created html when viewed with firebug:

[image: firebug]

Anyone have any ideas? This is very frustrating.. obviously, the firebug image is showing it not looking the way it should... if you guys need any more information please just ask

If its worth noting, im using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not posting your ajax request.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethtml.php?q="+str,true);
```

you are sending it via get. in php, try `print_r($_GET)` instead of `$_POST` and check if you see the right value.

Comment: @JohnDoe try opening firebug/developer tools and look at the XMLHttpRequest. you can see the method you are using to send as well as the url and variables you are sending via post/get. This allows you to double check you are sending to the server what you expect.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not looking in the right places, but i cant seem to find any place that it will show me what im sending, all I get is a more in depth view of the html to php xml script.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: on the page, press f12, go to the network tab. change the select and it should show the ajax request. you can see the url, method (and more) right there and if you click on the url you can see details of the request (post vars, response)

Comment: I think i found what we are looking for, when I submit it to the final php page, the developer panel actually shows the variables posted over, everything aperars to tranfer over INCLUDING the 12: ports:12 AND it is sent using the post method

Comment: Even the literal URL posted over carries the 12

Comment: Found my problem, i had two field with name ports somehow, and one, not being set, was clearing the other. Thanks for the pointers on the dev tools though.

Answer (score -1):

```
    foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
echo $row['Model'];
echo '<option value="'.$row['Model'].'">'.$row['Model'].'</option>';
$i++;
}
```

Look at line 2, above.

Comment: Nice catch, that explains why firebug was showing the 12 but not why it is posting over a whitespace rather than the value 12,

Comment: if it solved the problem..."...but not why it is posting over a whitespace rather than the value 12"